# How to pass parameters between two screens in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please, do not hurry to close this question as duplicate. I have read the official documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/) and so fa I have managed to pass successfully parameters between screens. There is som problem with my current case, and the solution is not obvious for me.

I have two screens. The first is called "Feed" and it belongs to bottom tab navigator. From the "Feed" screen I want to be able to navigate to "Comments" screen which is part of stack navigator.

I am able to successfully navigate between both screens, however, for some reason I am not able to pass any parameters when I navigate from "Feed" to "Comments".

Part of my "Feed" screen where I press "comments" icon:

```
      <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("passing param id: ", id);
            navigation.navigate("Comments", { id: id });
          }}
        >
          <FontAwesome name="comment-o" size={30} color="#0047AB" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

What I see on the console:

```
passing param id: some_id_whic_does_not_matter
```

I manage to successfully navigate to my "Comments" screen. Part of my "Comments" screen:

```
const CommentsScreen = (props) => {
  console.log("Comments Screen: ");
  console.log("comments: ", props);
```

What I see on the console for the route object:

```
route": Object {
    "key": "Comments-some-key",
    "name": "Comments",
    "params": undefined,
  }
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Where I am currently located on `NetworkNavigator` tab, and from there I want to navigate to the `Comments` screen.

I still dont see where the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I think we access params via `route` I mean

```
const CommentsScreen =({route})=>{
    const {id} = route.params;
    console.log(id);
...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your passed params via following

```
const CommentsScreen = (props) => {
  console.log("Comments Screen: ");
  console.log("comments: ", props.route.params.id);
```

**props.route.params**

It contains the object you passed in

```
navigation.navigation('screenname', {
...this object...
});
```

you can extract the data by using the same keys.

**Example**

```
navigation.navigation('screenname', {
  id: '1',
  name: 'Adam',
  age: 12
});

//Then you can access via 

  console.log("id: ", props.route.params.id);
  console.log("name: ", props.route.params.name);
  console.log("age: ", props.route.params.age);
```

Comment: I know, how I can access my props, the problem is that my props.route.params is undefined for some reason

Comment: Can you share your navigation details?

Comment: just edited, can you let me know, if now is better?

Comment: can you let me know one thing if your bottom bar is inside of StackNavigator?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/nesting-navigators#passing-params-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

So in my case:

```
navigation.navigate("Root Navigator", {
              screen: "Comments",
              params: { id: id },
            });
```